# Binomial inequality problem ${k+n-1 \choose k}\times{k+n+1 \choose k} \leq{k+n \choose k}^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, inequality, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Can anyone help we with this problem:
Let $a_n={k+n \choose k} $

Prove that $a_{k-1}a_{k+1}\leq a_k^2 $($\forall k$)
My first idea was using mathematical induction to proof that for every k element of natural number.  The basis is easy, but the problem is inductive step.

Comment: You have $\le$ in OP and $\ge$ in the title. What's correct?

Comment: hint : $\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ k\end{array}\right)=\frac{\underbrace{n(n-1)(n-2)...}k-times}{\underbrace{k(k-1)(k-2)...}k-times}$ expand it directly ...it's not hard to proof

Answer (score 1):

Simply write down
\begin{align}
\binom{k+n-1}{k}\binom{k+n+1}{k} = & \frac{(k+n-1)!(k+n+1)!}{(k!)^2(n-1)!(n+1)!}\\
= & \binom{k+n}{k}^2\frac{(k+n+1)(n-1)}{(k+n)(n+1)}
\end{align}
and show that the fraction we have in the last term is smaller than $1$ (which I'll let you do).